# Error while using datetime.strptime to convert a string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I want to convert a string in the following format to a datetime object in Python.

```
'2019-11-08T13:22:19.173700864-05:00'
```

I tried to use:

```
obj = datetime.strptime('2019-11-08T13:22:19.173700864-05:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000%z')
```

I got an error message. It seems `%f000` is not the correct way to convert 9-digit after the decimal point. And it seems I am also using `%z` in the wrong way.

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The microseconds is in nanoseconds format. I am not sure how you got this format. But, the python datetime() only supports nanoseconds. Are you still looking to format the nanoseconds to datetime() ?

Comment: Please go through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date

Comment: @roshan ok it's the response I get from an api call.

Comment: @Kalesh Kaladharan thanks.